# Firestore error: firebase_firestore, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

**My Flutter app has the following error:**

PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_firestore, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., {code: permission-denied, message: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.}, null))

**This is my Firestore Database:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 9, 24);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your firebase rules accept request only if there were made before the 24/09/2022.

Since we are today the 21/02/2023, you can't do any request.
You can simply update your database rules.

To accept **ALL** request, you can simply do:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: true
    }
  }
```

If you want that only authenticated user can make a request, you can do the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

You probably want to see more about [Cloud Firestore Security Rules.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)